# How to sum multiplication values from objects in an array?

Tags: javascript

if i have an array that looks like this :

```
    "orderItems": [
  {
    "description": "Test",
    "identifier": "Test identifier",
    "priceCent": 1,
    "lengthIn": 10,
    "widthIn": 5,
    "heightIn": 10,
    "weightLbs": 3,
    "quantity": 2
  },
{
    "description": "Test-2",
    "identifier": "Test identifier",
    "priceCent": 1,
    "lengthIn": 10,
    "widthIn": 5,
    "heightIn": 10,
    "weightLbs": 4,
    "quantity": 3
  }
]
```

How can I multiply weightLbs and quantity and sum those within the objects?
For example:

3 * 2 = 6
4 * 3 = 12

and result total I want is = 18

This is what I have so far, but this only adds weightLbs

```
        return delivery.order.orderItems.reduce((prev, curr) => {
      return prev + (curr.totalWeightLbs || 0);
    }, 0);
```

Comment: you need to multiply (curr.weightLbs*curr.quantity) and add

Comment: so return prev + (current.totalWeightLbs || 0 ) * (current.quantity || 0) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
orderItems.reduce((sum, currentItem) => { 
    return sum + (currentItem.weightLbs * currentItem.quantity); 
}, 0);
```

this will multiply the values and sum them in the `reduce` accumulator

Answer (score 0):

```js
const dummyArray = [
  {
    "description": "Test",
    "identifier": "Test identifier",
    "priceCent": 1,
    "lengthIn": 10,
    "widthIn": 5,
    "heightIn": 10,
    "weightLbs": 3,
    "quantity": 2
  },
{
    "description": "Test-2",
    "identifier": "Test identifier",
    "priceCent": 1,
    "lengthIn": 10,
    "widthIn": 5,
    "heightIn": 10,
    "weightLbs": 4,
    "quantity": 3
  }
];

let sum = 0;

for( i = 0; i < dummyArray.length; i++)
  sum += dummyArray[i].weightLbs * dummyArray[i].quantity

console.log(sum)
```

this might work